# Synchronicity with loops in promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Lately I'm messing around with promises. What I am trying to achieve in the `extractMovie()` is to loop through all the given urls, parse them, get some date, store it in an array and to resolve that array. But what actually happens is resolving the `result` (which is an empty array) and then looping through the urls. So actually an empty array is being resolved to the `parallel()` function. Any ideas on how to achieve that synchronicity in the promise?

```
const extractMovie = (movieUrl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fullUrl = mainDomain + movieUrl;
        domParser(fullUrl).then(($) => {
            const titleSelector = '.title h2';
            const ratingSelector = '.user_score_chart';
            const runtimeSelector = '.facts p:nth-child(9)';

            const obj = {
                title: $(titleSelector).html(),
                rating: $(ratingSelector).attr('data-percent'),
                runtime: $(runtimeSelector).text(),
            };
            resolve(obj);
        });
    });
};

const arrayProcessing = async (array) => {
    const results = [];
    for (const entry of array) {
        results.push(await extractMovie(entry));
    }
    return results;
};

const parallel = async (movieUrl1, movieUrl2) => {
    const task1 = arrayProcessing(movieUrl1);
    const task2 = arrayProcessing(movieUrl2);

    return {
        res1: await task1,
        res2: await task2,
    };
};

const run = async () => {
    try {
        const urls = await goInPage();
        await parallel(urls.page1, urls.page2).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

run();
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/157247) to the linked dupetarget question (disclosure: I wrote that answer) shows how to handle dealing with a bunch of promises, in series (which is what I think you want) or in parallel (but I don't think you want that). Pretty much right at the end of the answer.

Comment: I don't think that the questions are dublicates. My issue is realated with not understanding why the array is empty after the forEach.

Comment: That's exactly what the dupetarget addresses. You're logging your array **before** those promises resolve, so nothing has called `result.push` yet. Nothing in your function is waiting for the promises to complete before calling `resolve(result)`. The examples at the end of the answer I linked above are **exactly** applicable, in fact. :-)

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that when iterating the array I am using `forEach`, which is a function. In order to use `await` inside it, the loop has to be defined as `async`. That's where my issue comes. I rewrote my code with a normal `for` loop, but I really do want to use the `forEach` func. I editted my code in the question.

Comment: `forEach` loops through what you give it, synchronously, and calls its callback synchronously. (There are some libraries that offer an async variant of it.) But why do you want to use `forEach`? `for` or `for-of` are usually up to the task...

Comment: Side note: Your `parallel` is basically `Promise.all`, but using named properties instead of array slots... Example `Promise.all` use: `const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([urls.page1, urls.page2]);`.

Comment: And re `run`: Don't mix `await` and `then`. Use one or the other. Mixing them leads to dramatically confusing code. Your `await parallel(urls.page1, urls.page2).then(result => ...)` should be `const result = await parallel(urls.page1, urls.page2);` (or of course, using `Promise.all`).

Comment: Thanks for the await clarification. About the `forEach`  - when working with arrays, usually I use functions such as `.map` `.reduce` `.filter`. That's why I want to use `forEach` in the example so badly.